# Any advide on transfering iphone contacts to itunes?

Tags: iphone

So here's the thing, I accidently spilled water on my iphone 4, although it has been fixed, it still get kind of "unstable", sometimes it just suddenly shut itself down.
Now I'm saving money for the new iphone 5, but I have a pile of important contacts saved on my watered iphone 4 and I'm so afraid that they'll be gone with the damaged phone right before I could get a new one. But if I can copy these contacts to itunes, then next time I'll be able to transfer them to the new iphone,right? Or just copy to computer? Any difference?
Anyway, I just want the contacts to be backuped, any good idea? I don't mind if I have to pay for something but it would be the best if there's a free and easy way.Help me please.

Comment: this isn't a programming question and would probably be better anwered on [su].

Comment: [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) might work too.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open iTunes and plug in your iphone
2. Under the  “info” tab you will see a field that “Sync Contacts with :” and give you a choice of which program you want to save your contacts to .By default, it is Windows Address Book.
3. Check the “Sync Contacts With:”box and choose windows Address Book
4. In the lower-right corner click the sync button and all of your contacts will be immediately saved to Windows Address Book

Next time when you want to sync these contacts to your new iphone, you just add them to itunes library, and I belive you know how to do the rest.
Here I find some interesting articles about [how to transfer iphone contacts to itunes](http://www.m-reviews.com/how-to-transfer-files-from-iphone-to-itunes-on-PC.html), maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may first transfer your iPhone 4 contacts to your computer. And that may right there 
in your “Address Book” on your computer. If “Address Book” is in your dock, the icon 
is with “@” symbol. If not like that, go to Applications in Finder and do a search for 
`Address Book`

Next time, do an Address Book export just to have another back-up if you are not 
automatically backing up using Time Machine, your iDisk, or whatever. If you back up to a 
file on the same computer, copy it to an external drive.

There're so many trouble transfering from apple products to PC, As a lazy person I 
personally prefer using [a simple software iPhone Transfer Contact](http://www.levesoft.com/iPhone-transfer-contact.html), why bother?!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and activate Icloud for contacts and than go back to icloud in settings and make a backup. If you dont want to use Icloud connect it to your computer and at the startscreen in itunes there's a button with backup. But klick at first at the top called info there u can make synchronise changes. And tick the one where contacts be synchronised!

That would be the solution.